# Do programs invoked by shell inherit shell variables?

Tags: shell, quoting

If I have this shell script

```
str="A tremor in the Force.
The last time I felt it was in the presence of my old master."

cat <<< "$str"
```

My understanding is that the command

```
cat <<< "$str"
```

tells the shell to invoke the program `/bin/cat` and pass it the argument `$str` - where the double quotes around `$str` ensure that the shell will pass the  argument unaltered.  So if the `cat` program gets the `$str` variable unaltered - then it must be aware of the variables value?
My question is, does the shell pass variables declared in its environment to other system programs that it invokes?

Comment: Saying "pass it the argument `$str`" is not quite accurate.  As described in the answers below, the shell makes the contents of `$str` available on the standard input of `cat`.  `cat` does _not_ receive  `$str` as a command line argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does the shell pass variables declared in its environment to other system programs that it invokes?

Yes, but not in the case of `cat <<< "$str"`.

In Unix-like operating systems, most new programs are executed as a result of the `execve()` system all:

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

The shell uses `execv` to execute programs, and by default, the shell passes all environment variables in `envp`, similar to the way the command line arguments are passed in `argv`.  Conceptually, `envp` is an array strings each with the format `NAME=value`.

`man 2 execve` explains the entire process very clearly and includes working example code.

In the case of `cat <<<"$str"`, the shell supplies "$str" to `cat` on `cat`'s standard input, so `cat` never sees the variable named `str`, unless it was previously exported by the shell, for example by invoking `export str`, but `cat` has no way of knowing that the two are related.

`<<<` is a "Here String" and a shell extension.  From the `bash` man page:

> The word undergoes brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal.  Pathname expansion and word splitting are not performed.  The result is supplied as a single string to the command on its standard input.

The Here String is similar to the traditional idiom:

```
echo "$str" | cat
```

which I recommend.  Both, in fact, will add a newline at the end of standard input.  I believe both methods are identical, providing that `echo` does not modify the output in any way (which it can depending on the contents of string, so a safer version is `printf '%s' "$str"` instead of `echo`).

In your situation, I would use `printf '%s' "$str" | cat` because it's the most portable, universal, and easily understood, without locking your script into execution with only one of many shells.  If you use the POSIX `sh` man page for your shell script documentation, you will have less material to master, and the material you learn has application to all Bourne shell derivatives.

Comment: ah, ok. If I don't quote the `$str` variable the newline is not preserved, so what function  does the `"` serve in this situation?

Comment: does the shell evaluate the variable first - then apply the rules pertaining to double quotes ( preserve the newline/s that the string contained) before sending the result to `cat`'s `STDIN` ?

Comment: In few words, I think so... :-) Please see the updated answer.

Comment: The other difference in general is `command <<< "data"` is executed in the same shell while `printf '%s' "data" | command` may execute command in a subshell; for a program like `cat` this doesn't matter but for a builtin like `read` it does. Of course this `cat` (and many others) could be elided entirely.

Comment: Pretty good answer, but it conflates "environment variables" with "variables declared in its environment"—by which the asker appears to just be referring to shell variables. (`$str` is not an environment variable.) The paragraphs about `execve`/`envp`, while correct, are off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Programs invoked by a shell do not inherit shell variables. They only inherit environment variables. A variable is placed in the environment if you write `export str` (or in a few less common ways), not if you just assign to it.

`cat` wouldn't care about environment variables anyway.

The command `cat <<< "$str"` does not pass any argument to `cat`. It invokes `cat` with no argument, but with standard input connected to a pipe on which the shell writes the value of the variable `str` plus a newline. The `cat` process does not see `$str`, it sees `A tremor … my old master` (with a final newline). The double quotes around `$str` prevent word splitting and globbing from happening to the value of the variable: `"$str"` expands to exactly the value of `str`. You may be confusing double quotes with single quotes — `cat <<< '$str'` would pass the five-character string `$str` with a final newline as input to `cat`.

Comment: thanks, what confused me was that I thought the **purpose** of the double quotes was to *allow for expansion* of the variable - as opposed to single quotes where the literal string `$str` would be used. I thought then, once the double quotes had "done their job" they would be removed. but I realised that double quotes just allow variable expansion to occur - and that the double quotes still exist *after* the variable expansion. In effect its as if the the variable is expanded  *into* the double quotes - and the double quotes affect the result of the variable expansion.